# determine Fisher information of $N(0,\sigma^{2})$ over $\sigma^{2}$

Tags: stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, stochastic-calculus

So far i've got that $I(\sigma^{2}) = E_{\sigma^{2}}[\frac{\delta}{\delta \sigma^{2}}\log_{\sigma^{2}}(X)]^{2}$.

And i got that $\frac{\delta}{\delta \sigma^{2}}\log_{\sigma^{2}}(x) = \frac{x^{2}-\sigma^{2}}{2\sigma^{4}}$.

But what is $E_{\sigma^{2}}[\frac{x^{2}-\sigma^{2}}{2\sigma^{4}}]^{2}$

If i write this out i get a nasty integral, so i think there is an easier way out...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Case $I(\sigma)$

Using

$$I(\sigma)=-\mathbb E[\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \sigma^2}\log f(x,0,\sigma)|\sigma],$$

one computes

$$\log f(x,0,\sigma)=\log\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}$$

and arrives at

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma}\log f(x,0,\sigma)=-\frac{1}{\sigma}+\frac{x^2}{\sigma^3},$$
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \sigma^2}\log f(x,0,\sigma)=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}-\frac{3x^2}{\sigma^4}=\frac{\sigma^2-3x^2}{\sigma^4}.$$

Then

$$I(\sigma)=-\mathbb E[\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \sigma^2}\log f(x,0,\sigma)|\sigma]=
-\int_\mathbb R \frac{\sigma^2-3x^2}{\sigma^4}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx=\\
 -\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\int_\mathbb R\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx+
\frac{3}{\sigma^4}\int_\mathbb R\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx;$$

these integrals can be computed using the properties of the normal distribution (i.e. knowing its moments).

- Case $I(\sigma^2)$

In the case $I(\sigma^2)$, we introduce the parameter $\sigma^2:=y$, with $\sigma >0$. Then 
$$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi y}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2y}}.$$

We arrive at
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\log f=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left( -\log\sqrt{2\pi y}-\frac{x^2}{2y}\right)=
-\frac{1}{2y}+\frac{x^2}{2y^2}.$$

Then

$$I(\sigma^2)=\mathbb E[\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\log f(x,0,y)\right)^2|y]=
\int_\mathbb R 
\left(-\frac{1}{2y}+\frac{x^2}{2y^2}\right)^2\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi y}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2y}}dx=\\
 \frac{1}{4\sigma^4}\int_\mathbb R\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx-
\frac{1}{2\sigma^6}\int_\mathbb R\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx+
\frac{1}{4\sigma^8}\int_\mathbb R\frac{x^4}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}dx
.$$

All integrals can be computed knowing the moments of the normal distribution.

Comment: i see what i did wrong thanks! Still don't understand the minus though...

Comment: you are welcome! you can find the reason in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information.

Comment: i want $I(\sigma^{2})$ not $I(\sigma)$ or am i thinking the wrong way?

Comment: Do you need (not want) $I(\sigma^2)$? The normal distribution with mean $0$ variance $\sigma$ is denoted by $N(0,\sigma^2)$ and its density is given like in my answer. Do you agree with this notation? Why $I(\sigma^2)$?

Comment: I believe you need $I(\sigma)$, not $\sigma^2$. The variance of the given normal distribution is $\sigma$.

Comment: yes of course, but the question asks the fisher information over $\sigma^{2}$ So i thought that i needed to calculate $I(\sigma^{2})
$and so that i needed $\frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma^{2}} \log f(x)$. Because now we are constructing the fisher information about $\sigma$ right $I(\sigma)$?

Comment: In the case $I(\sigma^2)$, call $\sigma^2:=y$, with $\sigma >0$ with  $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi y}}exp(-\frac{x^2}{2y})$. The formula $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\log f$ leads to $(\frac{x^2}{2y^2}-\frac{1}{2y})^2$. This can be integrated, as well. Should I edit my answer?

Comment: yeah thats exactly what i had :)

Comment: done :-) i hope it helps